# Almost sure convergence of sequences

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of positive real numbers such that
$\sum_{n \geqslant 1} a_n < \infty $ and $$\sum_{n \geqslant 1} \Pr\left(\left|X_{n+1} - X_n\right| > a_n\right) < \infty $$

Why does $(X_n)$ converge almost surely?

Comment: Use the [Borel-Cantelli lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma).

Comment: This is not `stochastic-analysis`. Corrected the tags.

Comment: But the Borel-Cantelli Lemma doesn't say anything about the almost-surely convergency, right?

Answer (score 1):

As in the comment: Since $\sum_n {\Bbb P}(|X_{n+1} - X_n| > a_n)<\infty$, the [Borel-Cantelli lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel-Cantelli_lemma) implies that, with probability $1$, there are only finitely many $n$s such that $|X_{n+1}-X_n|>a_n$.  Since $\sum_n a_n$ is finite, this means that $\sum_n |X_{n+1}-X_n|$ is finite with probability $1$.  So, $\lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n\ge N} |X_n-X_{n+1}|=0$ a.s., which, by the triangle inequality, means that $(X_n)$ is a.s. Cauchy.  Therefore, $(X_n)$ almost surely converges.